# d3.js: enter-update-exit pattern - Old points not removed

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to do the enter-update-exit pattern on this graph below (which was built with the tremendous help of some very kind ppl here at SO but I am now stuck again unfortunately. I cant make the pattern work but I am certain I pick up the correct object (named `heatDotsGroup` in the code below).

I can however check in Chrome's developer tools that this object contains the nodes (ellipses) but the pattern doesn't work, therefore clearly I am doing something wrong.

Any ideas please? Many thanks!

```js
function heatmap(dataset) {
    
    var svg = d3.select("#chart")
        .select("svg")
    
    var xLabels = [],
        yLabels = [];
    for (i = 0; i < dataset.length; i++) {
        if (i==0){
            xLabels.push(dataset[i].xLabel);
            var j = 0;
            while (dataset[j+1].xLabel == dataset[j].xLabel){
                yLabels.push(dataset[j].yLabel);
                j++;
            }
            yLabels.push(dataset[j].yLabel);
        } else {
            if (dataset[i-1].xLabel == dataset[i].xLabel){
                //do nothing
            } else {
                xLabels.push(dataset[i].xLabel);                    
            }
        }
    };

    var margin = {top: 0, right: 25,
                  bottom: 60, left: 75};  

    var width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var dotSpacing = 0,
        dotWidth = width/(2*(xLabels.length+1)),
        dotHeight = height/(2*yLabels.length);

    var daysRange = d3.extent(dataset, function (d) {return d.xKey}),
        days = daysRange[1] - daysRange[0];
    
    var hoursRange = d3.extent(dataset, function (d) {return d.yKey}),
        hours = hoursRange[1] - hoursRange[0];    
    
    var tRange = d3.extent(dataset, function (d) {return d.val}),
        tMin = tRange[0],
        tMax = tRange[1];

    var colors = ['#2C7BB6', '#00A6CA', '#00CCBC', '#90EB9D', '#FFFF8C', '#F9D057', '#F29E2E', '#E76818', '#D7191C'];
    
    // the scale
    var scale = {
        x: d3.scaleLinear()
           .range([-1, width]),
        y: d3.scaleLinear()
           .range([height, 0]),
    };
    
    var xBand = d3.scaleBand().domain(xLabels).range([0, width]),
        yBand = d3.scaleBand().domain(yLabels).range([height, 0]);
    
    var axis = {
        x: d3.axisBottom(scale.x).tickFormat((d, e) => xLabels[d]),
        y: d3.axisLeft(scale.y).tickFormat((d, e) => yLabels[d]),
    };


    function updateScales(data){
        scale.x.domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.xKey)]),
        scale.y.domain([ 0, d3.max(data, d => d.yKey)])
    }

    var colorScale = d3.scaleQuantile()
        .domain([0, colors.length - 1, d3.max(dataset, function (d) {return d.val;})])
        .range(colors);

    var zoom = d3.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([1, dotHeight])
        .on("zoom", zoomed);

    var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
        .attr("id", "tooltip")
        .style("opacity", 0);

    // SVG canvas
    svg = d3.select("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .call(zoom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // Clip path
    svg.append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", "clip")
        .append("rect")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height+dotHeight);


    // Heatmap dots
    var heatDotsGroup = svg.append("g")
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
        .append("g");
        

    //Create X axis
    var renderXAxis = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        //.attr("transform", "translate(0," + scale.y(-0.5) + ")")
        //.call(axis.x)

    //Create Y axis
    var renderYAxis = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(axis.y);


    function zoomed() {
        d3.event.transform.y = 0;
        d3.event.transform.x = Math.min(d3.event.transform.x, 5);
        d3.event.transform.x = Math.max(d3.event.transform.x, (1 - d3.event.transform.k) * width);
        // console.log(d3.event.transform)

        // update: rescale x axis
        renderXAxis.call(axis.x.scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleX(scale.x)));

        // Make sure that only the x axis is zoomed
        heatDotsGroup.attr("transform", d3.event.transform.toString().replace(/scale\((.*?)\)/, "scale($1, 1)"));
    }
    
    svg.call(renderPlot, dataset)
    
    function renderPlot(selection, dataset){
        
        //Do the axes
        updateScales(dataset)
        selection.select('.y.axis').call(axis.y)
        selection.select('.x.axis')
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + scale.y(-0.5) + ")")
                .call(axis.x)
           
        
        // Do the chart
        const update = heatDotsGroup.selectAll("ellipse")
        .data(dataset);
        
        update
        .enter()
        .append("ellipse")
        .attr("cx", function (d) {return scale.x(d.xKey) - xBand.bandwidth();})
        .attr("cy", function (d) {return scale.y(d.yKey) + yBand.bandwidth();})
        .attr("rx", dotWidth)
        .attr("ry", dotHeight)
        .attr("fill", function (d) {
            return colorScale(d.val);}
            )
        .merge(update).transition().duration(800);   
        
        update.exit().remove();
        
    }


};
```

```css
#clickMe{
    height:50px;
    width:150px;
    background-color:lavender;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    
    <title>Heatmap Chart</title>

    <!-- Reference style.css -->
    <!--    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">-->

    <!-- Reference minified version of D3 -->
    <script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='heatmap_v4.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
</head>

<body>
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="click me to push new data" onclick="run();" />

    <div id='chart'>
    <svg width="700" height="500">
      <g class="focus">
        <g class="xaxis"></g>
        <g class="yaxis"></g>
      </g>
    </svg>
   </div>
    
   
    <script>
        function run() {
            var dataset = [];
                for (let i = 1; i < 360; i++) { //360
                    for (j = 1; j < 7; j++) {  //75
                        dataset.push({
                            xKey: i,
                            xLabel: "xMark " + i,
                            yKey: j,
                            yLabel: "yMark " + j,
                            val: Math.random() * 25,
                        })
                        }
                    };

                    heatmap(dataset)
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {});
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are not using the same selection each time you run the enter/exit/update cycle. When the button is pushed you:

1. Generate new data
2. Run the heatmap function
3. The heatmap function selects the svg and appends a fresh `g` called heatDotsGroup
4. The update function is called and passed the newly created `g` as a selection
5. The enter cycle appends everything because the new `g` is empty.

As a result both the exit and udpate cycles are empty. Try:

```
console.log(update.size(),update.exit().size()) // *Without any merge*
```

You should see both are empty each update. This is because all elements are entered each time, which why each update increases the number of ellipses.

I've pulled out a bunch of variable declarations and append statements from the heatmap function, things that only need to be run once (I could go further, but I just did a minimum). I've also merged your update and enter selection prior to setting attributes (as we want to set the new attributes if we update).The below snippet should demonstrate this change.

In the snippet, on button push the following happens:

1. Generate new data
2. Run the heatmap function
3. The heatmap function selects existing selections and doesn't append anything new
4. The update function is called and passed the selection used by previous update/enter/exit cycles containing any existing nodes.
5. The update function enters/exits/updates elements as needed based on the existing nodes.

Here's a working version based on the above:

```js
// Things to set/append once:
var svg = d3.select("#chart")
  .select("svg")

var margin = {top: 0, right: 25,bottom: 60, left: 75};  
var width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;
  
svg = svg.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var clip = svg.append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", "clip")
        .append("rect")


var heatDotsGroup = svg.append("g")
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
  .append("g");

var xAxis = svg.append("g").attr("class", "x axis");
var yAxis = svg.append("g").attr("class", "y axis")
     

        
function heatmap(dataset) {
    
    
    var xLabels = [],
        yLabels = [];
    for (i = 0; i < dataset.length; i++) {
        if (i==0){
            xLabels.push(dataset[i].xLabel);
            var j = 0;
            while (dataset[j+1].xLabel == dataset[j].xLabel){
                yLabels.push(dataset[j].yLabel);
                j++;
            }
            yLabels.push(dataset[j].yLabel);
        } else {
            if (dataset[i-1].xLabel == dataset[i].xLabel){
                //do nothing
            } else {
                xLabels.push(dataset[i].xLabel);                    
            }
        }
    };



    var dotSpacing = 0,
        dotWidth = width/(2*(xLabels.length+1)),
        dotHeight = height/(2*yLabels.length);

    var daysRange = d3.extent(dataset, function (d) {return d.xKey}),
        days = daysRange[1] - daysRange[0];
    
    var hoursRange = d3.extent(dataset, function (d) {return d.yKey}),
        hours = hoursRange[1] - hoursRange[0];    
    
    var tRange = d3.extent(dataset, function (d) {return d.val}),
        tMin = tRange[0],
        tMax = tRange[1];

    var colors = ['#2C7BB6', '#00A6CA', '#00CCBC', '#90EB9D', '#FFFF8C', '#F9D057', '#F29E2E', '#E76818', '#D7191C'];
    
    // the scale
    var scale = {
        x: d3.scaleLinear()
           .range([-1, width]),
        y: d3.scaleLinear()
           .range([height, 0]),
    };
    
    var xBand = d3.scaleBand().domain(xLabels).range([0, width]),
        yBand = d3.scaleBand().domain(yLabels).range([height, 0]);
    
    var axis = {
        x: d3.axisBottom(scale.x).tickFormat((d, e) => xLabels[d]),
        y: d3.axisLeft(scale.y).tickFormat((d, e) => yLabels[d]),
    };


    function updateScales(data){
        scale.x.domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.xKey)]),
        scale.y.domain([ 0, d3.max(data, d => d.yKey)])
    }

    var colorScale = d3.scaleQuantile()
        .domain([0, colors.length - 1, d3.max(dataset, function (d) {return d.val;})])
        .range(colors);

    var zoom = d3.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([1, dotHeight])
        .on("zoom", zoomed);

    var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
        .attr("id", "tooltip")
        .style("opacity", 0);

    // SVG canvas
    svg.call(zoom);


    // Clip path
  clip.attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height+dotHeight);



        

    //Create X axis
    var renderXAxis = xAxis 
        //.attr("transform", "translate(0," + scale.y(-0.5) + ")")
        //.call(axis.x)

    //Create Y axis
    var renderYAxis = yAxis.call(axis.y);


    function zoomed() {
        d3.event.transform.y = 0;
        d3.event.transform.x = Math.min(d3.event.transform.x, 5);
        d3.event.transform.x = Math.max(d3.event.transform.x, (1 - d3.event.transform.k) * width);
        // console.log(d3.event.transform)

        // update: rescale x axis
        renderXAxis.call(axis.x.scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleX(scale.x)));

        // Make sure that only the x axis is zoomed
        heatDotsGroup.attr("transform", d3.event.transform.toString().replace(/scale\((.*?)\)/, "scale($1, 1)"));
    }
    
    svg.call(renderPlot, dataset)
    
    function renderPlot(selection, dataset){
        
        //Do the axes
        updateScales(dataset)
        selection.select('.y.axis').call(axis.y)
        selection.select('.x.axis')
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + scale.y(-0.5) + ")")
                .call(axis.x)
           
        
        // Do the chart
        const update = heatDotsGroup.selectAll("ellipse")
        .data(dataset);
        
        update
        .enter()
        .append("ellipse")
        .merge(update)
        .attr("cx", function (d) {return scale.x(d.xKey) - xBand.bandwidth();})
        .attr("cy", function (d) {return scale.y(d.yKey) + yBand.bandwidth();})
        .attr("rx", dotWidth)
        .attr("ry", dotHeight)
        .attr("fill", function (d) {
            return colorScale(d.val);}
            )
         
        
        update.exit().remove();
        
    }


};
```

```css
#clickMe{
    height:50px;
    width:150px;
    background-color:lavender;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    
    <title>Heatmap Chart</title>

    <!-- Reference style.css -->
    <!--    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">-->

    <!-- Reference minified version of D3 -->
    <script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='heatmap_v4.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
</head>

<body>
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="click me to push new data" onclick="run();" />

    <div id='chart'>
    <svg width="700" height="500">
      <g class="focus">
        <g class="xaxis"></g>
        <g class="yaxis"></g>
      </g>
    </svg>
   </div>
    
   
    <script>
        function run() {
            var dataset = [];
                for (let i = 1; i < 360; i++) { //360
                    for (j = 1; j < 7; j++) {  //75
                        dataset.push({
                            xKey: i,
                            xLabel: "xMark " + i,
                            yKey: j,
                            yLabel: "yMark " + j,
                            val: Math.random() * 25,
                        })
                        }
                    };

                    heatmap(dataset)
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {});
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

*The exit selection here is still empty as the size of the data array is fixed. D3 assumes the new data replaces the old, but it can't know that the new data should be represented as new elements, unless of course we specify a key function as noted in a now deleted comment. This may or may not be the desired functionality that you want.*

Comment: Andrew and rioV8, a massive thanks guys!! You have greatly helped me and you give a very good insight of the enter-update-exit pattern In fact i did try to set the svg in the html code (those g elements in my html snippet are remainders of this effort) but I failed again to run the pattern successfully. Probably I was messing it up elsewhere

Comment: I wish I could accept both answers, both definitely deserve it, however I choose Andrew because he is a bit more detailed and because in my previous post you guys also gave amazing insights and I chose rioV8. So it looks fair to have a tie in total. (Sorry if it sounds silly...) Anyways....thanks a million again, I owe you a beer at least..Apologies for replying back so late, I hadnt managed to have a close look until now. Why dont you guys make a bl.ocks entry with this? I havent seen something similar there. Once again, many many thanks

Comment: @Aenaon, no problem, glad that we were able to help. As for the bl.ock it would be neat to see your final product if you're able to share (or show a limited version).

Answer (score 1):

I have a slightly different approach than Andrew.

A bunch of global variables will get messy when you have multiple charts.

When you click the button:

1. call the `renderPlot(dataset)`
2. check if we have a `#clip` element in the svg
3. if not: call `heatmap(dataset)`

   1. Construct all the static stuff and append to the svg.
   2. append a `datum` object to the svg with the variables needed for the update
4. fetch the `datum` from the svg
5. update the content of the svg using the `datum` object

```js
function heatmap(dataset) {

var svg = d3.select("#chart")
    .select("svg");

var xLabels = [],
    yLabels = [];
for (i = 0; i < dataset.length; i++) {
    if (i==0){
        xLabels.push(dataset[i].xLabel);
        var j = 0;
        while (dataset[j+1].xLabel == dataset[j].xLabel){
            yLabels.push(dataset[j].yLabel);
            j++;
        }
        yLabels.push(dataset[j].yLabel);
    } else {
        if (dataset[i-1].xLabel == dataset[i].xLabel){
            //do nothing
        } else {
            xLabels.push(dataset[i].xLabel);                    
        }
    }
};

var margin = {top: 0, right: 25,
              bottom: 60, left: 75};  

var width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var dotSpacing = 0,
    dotWidth = width/(2*(xLabels.length+1)),
    dotHeight = height/(2*yLabels.length);

var daysRange = d3.extent(dataset, function (d) {return d.xKey}),
    days = daysRange[1] - daysRange[0];

var hoursRange = d3.extent(dataset, function (d) {return d.yKey}),
    hours = hoursRange[1] - hoursRange[0];    

var tRange = d3.extent(dataset, function (d) {return d.val}),
    tMin = tRange[0],
    tMax = tRange[1];

var colors = ['#2C7BB6', '#00A6CA', '#00CCBC', '#90EB9D', '#FFFF8C', '#F9D057', '#F29E2E', '#E76818', '#D7191C'];

// the scale
var scale = {
    x: d3.scaleLinear()
       .range([-1, width]),
    y: d3.scaleLinear()
       .range([height, 0]),
};

var xBand = d3.scaleBand().domain(xLabels).range([0, width]),
    yBand = d3.scaleBand().domain(yLabels).range([height, 0]);

var axis = {
    x: d3.axisBottom(scale.x).tickFormat((d, e) => xLabels[d]),
    y: d3.axisLeft(scale.y).tickFormat((d, e) => yLabels[d]),
};

var colorScale = d3.scaleQuantile()
    .domain([0, colors.length - 1, d3.max(dataset, function (d) {return d.val;})])
    .range(colors);

var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, dotHeight])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("id", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);

// SVG canvas
svg .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .call(zoom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Clip path
svg.append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height+dotHeight);


// Heatmap dots
var heatDotsGroup = svg.append("g")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
    .append("g");

//Create X axis
var renderXAxis = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    //.attr("transform", "translate(0," + scale.y(-0.5) + ")")
    //.call(axis.x)

//Create Y axis
var renderYAxis = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(axis.y);


function zoomed() {
    d3.event.transform.y = 0;
    d3.event.transform.x = Math.min(d3.event.transform.x, 5);
    d3.event.transform.x = Math.max(d3.event.transform.x, (1 - d3.event.transform.k) * width);
    // console.log(d3.event.transform)

    // update: rescale x axis
    renderXAxis.call(axis.x.scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleX(scale.x)));

    // Make sure that only the x axis is zoomed
    heatDotsGroup.attr("transform", d3.event.transform.toString().replace(/scale\((.*?)\)/, "scale($1, 1)"));
}

var chartData = {};
chartData.scale = scale;
chartData.axis = axis;
chartData.xBand = xBand;
chartData.yBand = yBand;
chartData.colorScale = colorScale;
chartData.heatDotsGroup = heatDotsGroup;
chartData.dotWidth = dotWidth;
chartData.dotHeight = dotHeight;

svg.datum(chartData);

//svg.call(renderPlot, dataset)
}
function updateScales(data, scale){
    scale.x.domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.xKey)]),
    scale.y.domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.yKey)])
}

function renderPlot(dataset){
    
    var svg = d3.select("#chart")
        .select("svg");
    if (svg.select("#clip").empty()) { heatmap(dataset); }
    chartData = svg.datum();
    //Do the axes
    updateScales(dataset, chartData.scale);
    svg.select('.y.axis').call(chartData.axis.y)
    svg.select('.x.axis')
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + chartData.scale.y(-0.5) + ")")
            .call(chartData.axis.x)
    
    // Do the chart
    const update = chartData.heatDotsGroup.selectAll("ellipse")
    .data(dataset);
    
    update
    .enter()
    .append("ellipse")
    .attr("rx", chartData.dotWidth)
    .attr("ry", chartData.dotHeight)
    .merge(update)
    .transition().duration(800)
        .attr("cx", function (d) {return chartData.scale.x(d.xKey) - chartData.xBand.bandwidth();})
        .attr("cy", function (d) {return chartData.scale.y(d.yKey) + chartData.yBand.bandwidth();})
        .attr("fill", function (d) { return chartData.colorScale(d.val);} );
    
    update.exit().remove();
}
```

```css
#clickMe{
height:50px;
width:150px;
background-color:lavender;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Heatmap Chart</title>

<!-- Reference style.css -->
<!--    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">-->

<!-- Reference minified version of D3 -->
<script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='heatmap_v4.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
</head>

<body>
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="click me to push new data" onclick="run();" />

<div id='chart'>
<svg width="700" height="500">
  <g class="focus">
    <g class="xaxis"></g>
    <g class="yaxis"></g>
  </g>
</svg>
   </div>

   
<script>
    function run() {
        var dataset = [];
        for (let i = 1; i < 360; i++) { //360
            for (j = 1; j < 7; j++) {  //75
                dataset.push({
                    xKey: i,
                    xLabel: "xMark " + i,
                    yKey: j,
                    yLabel: "yMark " + j,
                    val: Math.random() * 25,
                })
            }
        };

        renderPlot(dataset)
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {});
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: rioV8, thank you again! Sorry I didnt accept your answer despite its completeness, see my comment below to Andrew for an explanation, albeit not the best one...

Comment: rioV8, I did a small change to your code, cause the margins for some reason the margins were behaving crazy and the y axis tick marks were not visible (for example, increasing the Left margin did move the chart at all), It took me almost the whole day yesterday to figure it out (still not 100% what happened...). Code below, I am now trying to fix the white space at the top and right and move the dots because they are getting cut-off. Code in  [plunker][1]


  [1]: https://plnkr.co/edit/EZAM825ZcNyjUefwMUjG?p=preview

Comment: Main changes, line 103, 157 and 171. I hope they make sense